# Comparação de números lido com "io.read()" não resulta em verdadeiro conforme esperado

Tags: if, tipagem, lua

Eu tentei colocar 1 e o segundo print não foi. Se eu trocar `x=io.read()` para "x=1" ele funciona normalmente

Segue o código

```lua
x = io.read()
if x ~= 0 then
    print(x.." diferente de 0")
end
if x == 1 then
    print(x.." igual a 1")
end
```

**Exemplo de entrada e saída:**

> 1
>  1 diferente de 0

Comment: Importante você `EDITAR` esta pergunta, explicando-a de forma clara, objetiva e direta, enfatizando a dificuldade encontrada. Além disso, nos forneça um [Exmplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) do problema, junto com sua tentativa de resolução. E mais, sugiro a leitura do [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Portugês](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs) para entender melhor o funcionamento da plataforma.

Comment: em lua quando você dá um io.read a entrada vem uma string...então comparando ele fica "1" == 1, por isso dá false, pra dar certo você poderia por exemplo converter esse io.read pra inteiro com o tonumber, ex : x = tonumber(io.read())

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Você colocou uma imagem do código e/ou mensagem de erro. Apesar de parecer uma boa ideia, não é! Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar o código e alterar algo dentro. [Veja mais sobre isso nesse link - Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/3774)

Answer (score 4):

Deve ser:

```lua
x = io.read()
if x ~= '0' then
    print (x .. ' deferente do 0')
end
if x == '1' then
    print (x .. ' igual a 1')
end
```

`io.read()` retorna strings.

Answer (score 4):

Você está comparando texto com número, então são valores diferentes, por isso dá falso e não entra no `if`. Assim é correto:

```
x = io.read()
if x ~= 0 then
    print(x .. " diferente de 0")
end
if x == "1" then
    print(x .. " igual 1")
end
if tonumber(x) == 1 then
    print(x .. " igual 1")
end
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/5W1WVB). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/stsmprjm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/ComparingTypes.lua).

Ou você compara texto com texto, ou converte o texto em número para comparar com número.

Não entrei no mérito que a conversão pode dar errada, e por isso precisaria ser testada antes de usar, então pode não ser uma boa usada de forma simples assim.

O primeiro `if` dá verdadeiro porque `"1"` é diferente de `0`, eles são de tipos diferentes, por isso nem precisa olhar para o valor de cada. Essa é a comparação correta.

Pode [ler mais sobre a função](http://lua-users.org/wiki/IoLibraryTutorial) usada que retorna sempre *string*.